# ASP.NET Core Application not Running in AWS Linux EC2 instance instead showing Apache Test Page

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline, asp.net-core-6.0

I have have an AWS CodePipeline process that gets the CodeCommit repository builds the application and publish the application to the Linux EC2 instances. The entire process executes successfully and I can see the final asp.net core application gets published to the /var/www/html/ folder. But when I get loads the URL of the load balancer (EC2 instances are behind a load balancer), I see the Apache test page, not the asp.net core application.

The asp.net core application I created is just the default asp.net core web application that gets created by default.

Below is the buildspec.yaml file. (This publishes a self contained application)

```js
version: 0.2
env:
    variables:
        DOTNET_CORE_RUNTIME: 6.0
phases:
    install:
        on-failure: ABORT
        runtime-versions:
            dotnet: ${DOTNET_CORE_RUNTIME}
        commands:
            - echo install stage - started `date`
    pre_build:
        commands:
            - echo pre build stage - stared `date`
            - echo restore dependencies started `date`
            - dotnet restore ./WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj
    build:
        commands:
            - echo build stage - started `date`
            - dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime linux-x64  ./WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj --self-contained
            - cp ./WebApplication1/appspec.yml ./WebApplication1/bin/Release/net6.0/linux-x64/publish/
artifacts:
    files:
        - '**/*'
        - appspec.yml
    name: artifact-test-cham
    discard-paths: no
    base-directory: ./WebApplication1/bin/Release/net6.0/linux-x64/publish/
```

And below is the appspec.yaml file that copies the content from the S3 artifact location to the /var/www/html/ folder

```js
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html/
```

Following image shows that the web application gets successfully published to the /var/www/html folder in the Linux EC2 instance with other asp.net core framework dependent files. But even though all the web application files along with other framework files are available, as I said, when I navigate through the load balancer I can see the Apache test page only.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for this issue, in publishing an ASP.NET Core web application in a AWS Linux EC2 instance, the answer is posted in the following URL, in the Amazon RePost site. Please use the below link to view the answer

https://repost.aws/questions/QUvNwkb4joTZylmomnQjjJaw/asp-net-core-application-not-running-in-aws-linux-ec-2-instance-instead-showing-apache-test-page

Any questions related to the solution you can post in that website or in here, will try my best to answer the question.